# Why can't I Triport from my Stronghold back to Luterra?

Tags: lost-ark

I am busy exploring an island and visited my Stronghold to collect some finished tasks and set new ones going.

Whilst I was there I had a quest to turn in to an NPC in Luterra, but when I checked the map all the Triports were greyed out, and I was unable to travel.

I had to use the Song of Escape to go back to the island from my Stronghold.

Why can't I Triport back to Luterra any more? Do I have to sail back there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot instantly triport between separate island continents. You *can* teleport between "continents" that are connected on the same landmass.

If the lands are disconnected by the water, your options are:

- Sail there
- Use a bifrost teleport that you left on the other continent. (Has a cooldown for setting a bifrost point and using it)
- Use a song teleport that you set on a main city (Luterra Castle has one but it has a cooldown) *Note: You can only have one of these set*